# 28-line Tikkun for Ester

Tags: product-recommendation, megillat-esther, safrus

I am looking for a 28-line tikkun sofrim for Ester which has the 10 b'nei Haman written within the same amud as either the prior, or subsequent text, rather than alone. Does anyone know where I could find such a tikkun?

I will be in Jerusalem later in the month, so if someone knows a store in J-lem where I could get one, it would also be a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Kenigsburg in Meah shearim. He's located on 72 Shmuel Salant, if I recall correctly. Rabbi Yaakov Chenegal in Bnei Berak also does custom tikkunim on demand if you can't find a regular one.

Edit: I don't have either phone number but you can probably find them in Israeli phone directories.

Comment: Thanks Yitzchak, I'll probably head to Meah Shearim while I'm in Jlem, because I also need a new mezuzah klaf (or few) and I know better than to buy them in the shuk. Have you been by Kenigsburg? Does he also sell klaf and dyo? What are his prices like?

Comment: Kenigsburg was my regular klaf supplier when I was in Israel, and I understand that his prices are pretty reasonable.